# Access parent model data from child in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, parent

I am building small web application with ASP.NET MVC C#. I have two models:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ParentId{ get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And I have ParentView where I send Parent Id to Child Controller with ActionLink, like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("something", "ChildIndexMethod", "ChildController", new { parentId=item.Id}, null)
```

When clicked, we go to ChildIndexView and list of all Children under Parent model. From there, what I want is to be able to create new Child under same Parent. To create new Child I need to provide ParentId to a new Child object. How can I retrieve that ParentId and pass it to Child?

I did this:

```
if (Model.FirstOrDefault() != null) 
    { 
        @Html.ActionLink("New child", "NewChild", new { parentId = Model.FirstOrDefault().ParentId})
    }
    else
    {
        //What to do if Model is null?
    }
```

First I check if Model is not null. If it is not null, I take FirstOrDefault object from model and pass ParentId to a Child. But it only works if there are Children already under Parent. IF there are no Children under Parent, I cannot read ParentId and thus error occurs. How can I send ParentId to a Child element from this position?

I know this is probably wrong method to achieve my goal. But I am still learning. Also, I was not able to find answer on SO. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Model in the children view is an `IEnumerable<Child>`. You have two options:

Define a new viewmodel which contains the list of Child and the parentid:

```
public ChildListViewModel
{
    public Guid ParentId {...}
    public IEnumerable <Child> Children {...}
}
```

Use view bag

```
ViewBag.ParentId = parentId;
```

Both will make ParentId available in your view even if you don't have any Child

Comment: Model in Children View is PagedList, but both of your methods were on the spot. Thank you

Comment: So instead on IEnumerable<Child> you can use PagedList. Regards